# Where is scala's List.cons method?

Tags: scala

Where is Scala's List.cons? I cannot find it in my settings.

```
scala> List.::
<console>:12: error: value :: is not a member of object List
       List.::
            ^

scala> List.cons
<console>:12: error: value cons is not a member of object List
       List.cons
            ^
```

If I type List.[tab] to auto-complete, I get

```
scala> List.
!=   ->                    ReusableCBF    canBuildFrom   ensuring   fill        hashCode       ne           notifyAll      tabulate     wait
##   ==                    apply          concat         eq         formatted   isInstanceOf   newBuilder   range          toString     →
+    GenericCanBuildFrom   asInstanceOf   empty          equals     getClass    iterate        notify       synchronized   unapplySeq
```

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L97

Comment: If you press `tab` not after object `List` but after instance e.g. `List(1)` you'll see methods `++              flatMap              min                 sortBy          
++:             flatten              minBy               sortWith        
+:              fold                 mkString            sorted          
/:              foldLeft             nonEmpty            span            
:+              foldRight            orElse              splitAt         
::              forall               padTo               startsWith  ...`

Answer (score 5):

It is on the class `List`, not on the object `List`.

```
scala> List(1).::
   def ::[B >: Int](elem: B): List[B]
```